# contenedores inferiores no se ajustan al contenedor superior

Tags: html, css

ayuda por favor, el problema es que las etiquetas fieldset se desajustan de su contenedor en la parte derecha de la hoja, cuando se vizualiza en dispositivos pequeños : [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```css
*{box-sizing: border-box;}
#controlesFactura{
    margin-bottom: 7px;
}
.btn{
    border: 2px solid black;
    background-color:  #4CAF50;
    color: white;
    padding: 14px 28px;
    font-size: 16px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.enviar{
    border-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
}
.enviar:hover {
  background-color: #339933;
  color: white;
}
#tablaFactura{
    border: 5px solid black;
}
/*ESTILOS FACTURA*/
#clienteDatos input[type=text]{
    width: 100%;
    /*border:none;*/
}
#tblFactura{
  border:#339933;
}
/*CENTRANDO LA FACTURA*/
#facturaContenedor{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: flex-start;
    overflow: auto;
}
/*FACTURA GENERAL*/
#facturaCabecera, #facturaCliente, #facturaItems{
    width: 100%;
}

/*TAMAÑOS DE CELDAS TABLA ITEMS*/
.faCodP{
    width: 30px;
}
.faDesP{
    width: 200px;
}
.faCanP{
    width: 40px;
}
.faPreP{
    width: 50px;
}
.faSub{
    width: 70px;
}
.faIva{
    width: 40px;
}
.faTot{
    width: 80px;
}
#facturaItems input[type=text]{
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Factura</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <!--HOJAS DE ESTILO-->
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/estilosFactura.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/estilosGenerales.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="contenedores">
            <fieldset id="facturaCabecera">
                <legend>Datos Factura</legend>
                <table>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td>001</td>
                            <td>001</td>
                            <td>00000</td>
                            <td>claveacces111111111111111111111</td>
                            <td>fecha11111111111111</td>
                            <td style="width: 5%;"></td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
             </fieldset>
            <fieldset id="facturaCliente">
                <legend>Datos Cliente</legend>
                <table>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td><select><option>Consumidor Final</option></select></td>
                            <td><input type="text"></td>
                            <td><input type="button" value="Buscar"></td>
                            <td><a>Nuevo Cliente</a></td>
                            <td style="width:5%;"></td>
                        </tr>
                     </tbody>
                </table>
                <div id="clienteDatos">
                    <input type="text">
                    <input type="text">
                    <input type="text">
                    <input type="text">
                    <input type="text">
                </div>
             </fieldset>
            <fieldset id="facturaItems">
                <legend>Items</legend>
                <div id="facturaContenedor">
                    <table id="tblFactura">
                        <thead class="tablaCabecera">
                            <tr>
                                <th>Cod</th>
                                <th>Descripcion</th>
                                <th>Cant</th>
                                <th>P.Unit</th>
                                <th>Subtotal</th>
                                <th>Iva</th>
                                <th>P.Total</th>
                                <th>Eliminar</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody class="tablaCuerpo">
                            <tr>
                                <td class="faCodP"><input type="text"></td>
                                <td class="faDesP"><input type="text"></td>
                                <td class="faCanP"><input type="text"></td>
                                <td class="faPreP"><input type="text"></td>
                                <td class="faSub"><input type="text"></td>
                                <td class="faIva"><input type="text"></td>
                                <td class="faTot"><input type="text"></td>
                                <td class="faEli"><input type="button" value="Eliminar"></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td class="faCodP"><input type="text"></td>
                                <td class="faDesP"><input type="text"></td>
                                <td class="faCanP"><input type="text"></td>
                                <td class="faPreP"><input type="text"></td>
                                <td class="faSub"><input type="text"></td>
                                <td class="faIva"><input type="text"></td>
                                <td class="faTot"><input type="text"></td>
                                <td class="faEli"><input type="button" value="Eliminar"></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td class="faCodP"><input type="text"></td>
                                <td class="faDesP"><input type="text"></td>
                                <td class="faCanP"><input type="text"></td>
                                <td class="faPreP"><input type="text"></td>
                                <td class="faSub"><input type="text"></td>
                                <td class="faIva"><input type="text"></td>
                                <td class="faTot"><input type="text"></td>
                                <td class="faEli"><input type="button" value="Eliminar"></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td class="faCodP"><input type="text"></td>
                                <td class="faDesP"><input type="text"></td>
                                <td class="faCanP"><input type="text"></td>
                                <td class="faPreP"><input type="text"></td>
                                <td class="faSub"><input type="text"></td>
                                <td class="faIva"><input type="text"></td>
                                <td class="faTot"><input type="text"></td>
                                <td class="faEli"><input type="button" value="Eliminar"></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td class="faCodP"><input type="text"></td>
                                <td class="faDesP"><input type="text"></td>
                                <td class="faCanP"><input type="text"></td>
                                <td class="faPreP"><input type="text"></td>
                                <td class="faSub"><input type="text"></td>
                                <td class="faIva"><input type="text"></td>
                                <td class="faTot"><input type="text"></td>
                                <td class="faEli"><input type="button" value="Eliminar"></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td class="faCodP"><input type="text"></td>
                                <td class="faDesP"><input type="text"></td>
                                <td class="faCanP"><input type="text"></td>
                                <td class="faPreP"><input type="text"></td>
                                <td class="faSub"><input type="text"></td>
                                <td class="faIva"><input type="text"></td>
                                <td class="faTot"><input type="text"></td>
                                <td class="faEli"><input type="button" value="Eliminar"></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td class="faCodP"><input type="text"></td>
                                <td class="faDesP"><input type="text"></td>
                                <td class="faCanP"><input type="text"></td>
                                <td class="faPreP"><input type="text"></td>
                                <td class="faSub"><input type="text"></td>
                                <td class="faIva"><input type="text"></td>
                                <td class="faTot"><input type="text"></td>
                                <td class="faEli"><input type="button" value="Eliminar"></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td class="faCodP"><input type="text"></td>
                                <td class="faDesP"><input type="text"></td>
                                <td class="faCanP"><input type="text"></td>
                                <td class="faPreP"><input type="text"></td>
                                <td class="faSub"><input type="text"></td>
                                <td class="faIva"><input type="text"></td>
                                <td class="faTot"><input type="text"></td>
                                <td class="faEli"><input type="button" value="Eliminar"></td>
                            </tr>


                        </tbody>
                        <tfoot class="tablaPie">
                            <tr>
                                <td>subotoal</td>
                                <td>0.00</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Grava 0</td>
                                <td>0.00</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Grava Iva</td>
                                <td>0.00</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Iva</td>
                                <td>0.00</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Total</td>
                                <td>0.00</td>
                            </tr>
                        </tfoot>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </fieldset>
        </div>
     </body>
</html>
```

Comment: He ejecutado el código en la propia pregunta y luego lo he descargado y probado en local, pero no consigo reproducir el problema. ¿Falta algo en la pregunta?

Comment: Alvaro Montoro, gracias por responder, en un ordenador normal  se observa normal, pero al probar en version movil con la herramienta del propio navegador se ve la diferencia como esta en la imagen que publique en la pregunta, si mira en la parte derecha del html no estan en alineados.

Comment: No sé que es lo que pasa con las herramientas del programador (modo responsivo 420x645, como en la imagen) que unas veces puedo ver el problema y otras no. Parece que la causa es que las tablas tienen un ancho superior a los 420 píxeles y eso hace que se salgan del contenedor padre, siendo el segundo fieldset el único que realmente cumple con lo esperado. Es decir, la línea roja donde indicas dónde debería ir los fieldset debería ir con el final del segundo fieldset (el único que se ajusta bien a los 420px)

Comment: entonces, ¿que puedo hacer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La causa es que las tablas tienen un ancho superior a los 420 píxeles y eso hace que se salgan del contenedor padre, siendo el segundo fieldset el único que realmente cumple con lo esperado. Es decir, la línea roja donde indicas dónde debería ir los fieldset debería ir con el final del segundo fieldset (que es el único que se ajusta bien a los 420px).

En particular, parece que el problema ocurre porque los títulos de las tablas y los contenidos de las celdas *empujan* el tamaño de la tabla más allá de lo permitido. Una posible solución para esto es decirle al navegador que rompa las palabras que son demasiado grandes dentro de las tablas. Algo que podrías hacer añadieno esto a tu CSS:

```
table tr td, table tr th {
  word-break: break-word;
}
```

Entonces las tablas (y los fieldset) ya se ajustarán bien al ancho, aunque las palabras largas se romperán en varias filas:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

Otra opción sería reducir el tamaño del texto para pantallas más pequeñas usando media queries. Algo como esto:

```
@media (max-width: 420px) {
  table tr td, table tr th {
    font-size: 0.65em;
  }
}
```

que se vería así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aunque podrías encontrarte con el mismo problema (porque realmente las celdas se reajustarán automáticamente de tamaño y podría ocurrir el problema de nuevo.

Otra opción sería combinar las dos cosas:

```
@media (max-width: 420px) {
  table tr td, table tr th {
    font-size: 0.65em;
    word-break: break-word;
  }
}
```

Pero de nuevo, se deja algo de control al navegador, lo que puede resultar en visualizaciones inesperadas (aunque siempre quedarán limitadas a los 420px de ancho).

Comment: Gracias Alvaro por la respuesta, pero no es precisamente lo que busco

Comment: @Felix edite la respuesta con variantes. Pensaba que lo que querías era que se ajustaran todos los fieldset al ancho total. ¿Qué es lo que buscas precisamente? ¿Cómo se ve mal la solución propuesta? Si supera exactamente lo que quieres, podría dar una mejor solución.

Comment: Gracias Alvaro, me sirve la opcion en la cual se combina el media query.